How to get VPC's associated with site to site VPN connections using boto3 for aws?
i have some vpc's associated with Site to SIte VPN connection's. using VPC ID i want to get vpn connection's associated with that perticulat VPC id.
i tried describe_vpcs, describe_subnets, describe_vpn_connections but couldn't find the solutions

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can filter vpn gateways by VPC id as documented here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_vpn_gateways.html

I'm not sure why the community bot flagged this as unclear. It's a perfectly clear question.
